# I get an error when I make my own spring boot query

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, crud-repository

My problem is when I try to make a customized query, I want to use `crud` or `jpa` repositories for my repository to make custom methods to do the following operations on the database, but I can't succeed in any way...

**CartRepository**

```
package com.example.registrationlogindemo.repository;

import com.example.registrationlogindemo.model.Cart;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
public interface CartRepository extends CrudRepository<Cart,Long> {

    @Query(name = "INSERT INTO cart VALUES (:productID,:userID)",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Cart> save(@Param("productID") Long productId, @Param("userID") Long userID);

    @Query(name = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE user_id = ?2",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Cart>showAll(Long productID, Long userID);
}
```

**Cart**

```
package com.example.registrationlogindemo.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;


@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "cart")
public class Cart {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class CartController {
    
    private static SessionFactory factory;
    Long saveId;
    
    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    CartRepository cartRepository;

    @GetMapping("/shoppingCart")
    @ResponseBody
    public String showCart(Model model, Principal principal){
        String nume = principal.getName();
        cartRepository.save(saveId,userRepository.AiciVoiAveaId(nume));
        Optional<Product> product = productRepository.findById(saveId);
        model.addAttribute("product", product.get());
        return "shoppingCart";
    }

    @PostMapping("/shoppingCart/{id}")
    public String shoppingCart(@PathVariable Long id){
        saveId = id;
        return "redirect:/shoppingCart";
    }

}
```

Error

```
    2023-01-05T15:39:16.146+02:00  WARN 16652 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cartRepository' defined in com.example.registrationlogindemo.repository.CartRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.example.registrationlogindemo.repository.CartRepository.save(java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.registrationlogindemo.repository.CartRepository.save(java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long); No property 'save' found for type 'Cart'

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cartRepository' defined in com.example.registrationlogindemo.repository.CartRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.example.registrationlogindemo.repository.CartRepository.save(java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.registrationlogindemo.repository.CartRepository.save(java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long); No property 'save' found for type 'Cart'
```

Can someone help me?

Hi, I have a problem too, I try to create a specific query for several actions and I get errors and I don't understand why...

Comment: Your save returns a `List<Cart>` how do you expect that to work? Also you are passing 2 values to your other query but are only using 1. You also don't explain what errors you get, should we guess?

Comment: I added the errors, for second parameters i removed one, for example query what type return to save him as what?

Comment: The `save` needs an `@Modifying` but I wonder why all the hassle if you are using JPA in the first place, feels like you are trying very hard to work around the fact that you are using JPA.

Comment: I'm wondering why this line `cartRepository.save(saveId,userRepository.AiciVoiAveaId(nume));` won't give NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

Salut,

You can try with JpaRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface CartRepository extends JpaRepository<Cart, Long> {

    @Query("FROM Cart WHERE user.id = :userID")
    List<Cart> findAllByUserId(Long userID);
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "cart")
public class Cart {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user", nullable = false)
    private User user;

}
```

And then you can use the repository like so:

```
Cart cartToBeSaved = new Cart(userId);
cartRepository.save(cartToBeSaved); //cart id is auto-generated
```

Also, I would avoid declaring a global `Long saveId;`. It has no useful purpose and can lead to more serious issues when multiple users are accessing these endpoints.

I would also move some logic in a service class and I would encapsulate the repositories.

For example:

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CartController {

    private final CartService cartService;

    @GetMapping("/shoppingCart")
    public String showCart(Model model, Principal principal) {
        Product product = cartService.saveProduct(...);
        model.addAttribute("product", product.get());
        return "shoppingCart";
    }


    @PostMapping("/shoppingCart/{id}")
    public String shoppingCart(@PathVariable Long id){
        //something here
    }

}
```

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CartService {

    private final ProductRepository productRepository;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final CartRepository cartRepository;

    public Product saveProduct(...) {
        //some business logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: I hate spring boot, I tried but it didn't work, could you help me in the chat?

Answer (score 0):

Your `save()` method contains a faulty sql command. The `INSERT` command for SQL does not work this way. I don't know exactly the qualities of your `Cart` object, but it needs to look like the following way.

```
 @Modifying
 @Query(name = "INSERT INTO cart (productId, userId) VALUES (:productID,:userID)",nativeQuery = true)
 Cart save(@Param("productID") Long productId, @Param("userID") Long userID);
```

A SQL `INSERT` command must contain the column names of the corresponding table.

I also recommend using `@Modifying` annotation for commands such as `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`. You can find detailed information about `@Modifying` anatotion [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-modifying-annotation).

Comment: I modified as you said but I get the same errors

Comment: Change the `List<Cart>` expression to `Cart`.